# Google Calendar won't update ics feed when new events are added

Tags: google-calendar-api, webcal

I have a published .ics file that my users can add to their google calendar via a url. The trouble is that google seems to be caching the feed and new events aren't showing up. The only solution I've come up with is to manually remove the calendar and re-add it with a slightly different url by adding `?nocache=asdfasdfsdf` to the end. Is there something in the ics spec that would solve this problem that doesn't require intervention by users?